# Die Deklination der Kardinalzahlen

Tags: declension

Es wird z.B *»einer meiner Freunde«* gesagt. Und dann *»zwei meiner Freunde«*. Können wir *»zweier meiner Freunde«* sagen und warum nicht?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Da *einer* Singular ist und *zwei* Plural, solltest Du nicht die selbe Endung erwarten, denke zum Beispiel an *dieser/diese*. Es käme höchstens *zweie* in Betracht, und [das war tatsächlich mal üblich](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Beugung-von-Zahlwortern), gilt heute aber als falsch.